# Copying one cell to a list in column form

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have a list of data and formulas in excel that change when I refresh the page or modify a value within the spreadsheet.

I would like to copy the value of one cell, into a column/list of sorts of hundred if not thousands of times to create a list of results that I can work out max, min, and average over a large span of results.

SpreadSheet Example:
[image: SpreadSheet Example]

In the image above, I would like to copy the contents of cell C7 to either a new sheet or column, to make a list of the numbers it shows upon each refresh. Keep in mind the cell auto recalculates when pasting.

Comment: Paste Special >> Values ? Or do you need this to be an automated process?

Comment: Automated process, That value at C7 changes all the time, it shows me the MAX number in a list of 144000 numbers, i need to copy that value to another column, refresh the information, then copy the same cell to a new row on the same column as the last.

Comment: @Jebula999 What sheet/column are you copying the data to? How are you refreshing the sheet? When is the column of maxes cleared out, if ever, and how do you plan to take action on that?

Comment: also: What triggers a change in the value of cell C7?

Comment: Column A uses =RAND()*99.99 to pick a random number, Column B shows a 1 if the number in column A is smaller than the number shown in B1.

Column C is where it counts the 0's in a row.

Everytime i hit F9 or change any value on the page the list of numbers in Column A generate a new list of random numbers, and hence the value in C& changes.



What i currently do is copy cell C7 then paste it to another free column, any free column.

I would like to automate the copying and pasting of the value in C7 into another column, over and over again.